# Why doesn't my header() function redirect?

Tags: php, xml, header

I have the following script that recieves an xml file and reads it with `file_get_contents()`. I want to redirect this xml to a file called "register" but it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

```
 <?php
     $xml_post=file_get_contents('php://input');
     $xml=simplexml_load_string($xml_post);
     if($xml->action=='register')
       {
        header('Location: http://proiectis.host22.com/register.php');
        exit;
      }

 ?>
```

I would appreciate your help.

This is my xml:

```
  <xml version="1.0">

     <action>register</action>

     <parameters>

          <name>Ionel Popescu</name>

          <username>Ionel P</username>

      <email>ionel@popescu.com</email>

      <password>abdef01</password>

    </parameters>

    </xml>
```

Comment: are you sure `$xml->action` does equal `register`?

Comment: what is the contents of `$xml`?

Comment: @Diana Prior to your `if`, add `var_dump( $xml );`

Comment: White-space? Warnings turned on?

Comment: Has something else triggered the sending of headers?  Any output at all before the point you call header() will cause header() to fail because the headers will have already been sent.  Something as simple as whitespace at the start of your PHP script can trigger output.

Comment: What do you mean "redirect this xml"? You want to pass the XML to the other URL?

Comment: @GordonM i know that and i don't have white spaces or anything outputted.

Comment: @bfavaretto exactly, i need to pass the xml to other url, because i will recieve more xml-s and i have to filter them and pass to the correct script(e.g. register, login etc).

Comment: So you have to `include`, not redirect.

Comment: i also included this file into "register.php" , but firstly i have to get there with that header

Comment: Diana, when you redirect with header, nothing is passed to the redirected url, it's like entering a new address in the browser address bar. You have to rethink you application's flow.

Comment: @bfavaretto So i cannot send the xml from this file to "register.php"? In "register.php" i also have "file_get_contents() to read the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding in the XML document.
You have no XML header in your document but you use the `<xml>`-element as the root element.
Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!-- This is a typical xml header -->
<result> <!-- An xml document must contain exactly 1 root element -->
  <action>register</action>
  <parameters>
    <name>Ionel Popescu</name>
    <username>Ionel P</username>
    <email>ionel@popescu.com</email>
    <password>abdef01</password>
  </parameters>
</result>
```

The original PHP code should work now.

Comment: i have only one root element and that is <xml version"1.0"> </xml>

Comment: Then you should check `$xml_post`. I tried your original version [here](http://codepad.org/s13tfx0r) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if ((string) $xml->action === 'register') {
  // code
}
```

And you don't need the `</xml>` in your xml file.

Comment: If you're going to cast the value, you might as well match by type also: `===`

Comment: it doesn't need to be casted...i tested "echo $xml->action" and it outputs "register" , so this works fine. There's something wrong with header() i guess...

Answer (score 0):

`$xml->action` returns `SimpleXMLElement` instead of string which you expected. So use this code:

```
 <?php
     $xml_post=file_get_contents('php://input');
     $xml=simplexml_load_string($xml_post);
     if((string)$xml->action == 'register')
       {
        header('Location: http://proiectis.host22.com/register.php');
        exit;
      }

 ?>
```

Comment: this is my output after var_dump :

object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "register"
}